# (android) Nullpointer exception while setting a spinner

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

Hello everyone my problem is this : From an activity by a fragment as follows:

```
fragmentoEquipos = AgrupacionEquipos.newInstance(codigoTemporal);
```

(Using the recomended Google way)

In the fragment I set a spinner using an adapter:

```
ColorSpinnerAdapter

package com.enjines.gestiondeportiva;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ColorSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<Integer> colores;
    List<String> coloresNombre;
    Context context;

    public ColorSpinnerAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        colores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int retrieve [] = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.groupColors);
        for(int re:retrieve)
        {
            colores.add(re);
        }

        coloresNombre = Arrays.asList(context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colorsName));

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return colores.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0)
    {
        return colores.get(arg0);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0)
    {
        return arg0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);


        TextView txv = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        txv.setBackgroundColor(colores.get(pos));

        if (pos == 6){
            txv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }
        txv.setTextSize(20f);
        txv.setText(coloresNombre.get(pos));
        Log.e("gestiondeportiva", "Devolvemos la vista del adapter del spinner");
        return view;
    }

}
```

This is the code extracted from de adapter:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Spinner spnColors = (Spinner) fragmento.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        adaptador = new ColorSpinnerAdapter(getActivity());
        spnColors.setAdapter(adaptador);
}

fragmento is the view:
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fragmento = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_agrupacion_equipos2, container, false);
.
.
.
.
        return(fragmento);
}
```

In my activity y load the fragment and all runs fine. Then I moved to another fragment and everything is working well. Returning to the fragment containing the spinner get an exception :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.enjines.gestiondeportiva, PID: 15998
                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.height' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:6427)
                                                                                  at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:6703)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                                  at android.widget.Spinner.setUpChild(Spinner.java:657)
                                                                                  at android.widget.Spinner.makeView(Spinner.java:620)
                                                                                  at android.widget.Spinner.getBaseline(Spinner.java:456)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1120)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
                                                                                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2618)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2019)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1177)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1383)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1065)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5901)
                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)
```

I have the spinner in a linear layout as in the original project have two spinner sharing the space. If I remove the linear layout everything is working properly . But I need to distribute the horizontal space with the two spinners. Thanks.

Edit:
These are my activity layout and my fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.enjines.gestiondeportiva.NuevaAgrupacion">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/no_existen_agrupaciones"
        android:id="@+id/no_existen_agrupaciones"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/NuevaAgrupacionContenedor"
        android:layout_below="@+id/no_existen_agrupaciones"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnSiguienteFragmento">

    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/anterior"
        android:id="@+id/btnAnteriorFragmento"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txtOmitir"
        android:id="@+id/btnOmitir"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnAnteriorFragmento"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/siguiente"
        android:id="@+id/btnSiguienteFragmento"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/NuevaAgrupacionContenedor"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/NuevaAgrupacionContenedor"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context=".Fragments.AgrupacionEquipos">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="280dip"
            android:layout_height="60dip"
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:transitionGroup="false"
            android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:contentDescription="@string/DescriptcionColorPrincipal1"
            android:contextClickable="false"
            android:dropDownWidth="fill_parent"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:gravity="top|left"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You should include your relevant layouts.

Comment: Aded activity layout and frame layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved the problem. as was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176877/weird-nullpointerexception-in-spinner):

In my adaper I used:

```
view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
```

instead of

```
view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should bind your fragment views inside of onViewCreated(); so please change your code to look as follows and see if it works

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_agrupacion_equipos2, container, false);

Spinner spnColors = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            adaptador = new ColorSpinnerAdapter(getActivity());
            spnColors.setAdapter(adaptador);

            return(view);
    }
```

Comment: In "createView" the result is the same that in "onActivityCreate". Before, it was in this function. When I got the exception for first time I search about my problem and one solution that I saw here was that. It seems to be something related with the positions of the elements in screen and how android calculate them.