# NullPointerException on inflating Spinner in MvvmCross causes app to crash on Android 4.4

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

On Android 4.4 when showing a fragment that contains a MvxSpinner that is bound to a collection (either a List or ObservableCollection) with elements in it, a NullPointer is thrown.

If the collection is empty, the exception is not thrown.

The same code works on Android 4.3 without a problem.

The stack trace is the same as found in [Android app crashes with NullPointerException in ChoreoGrapher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533006/android-app-crashes-with-nullpointerexception-in-choreographer/19965168#19965168) and [Weird NullPointerException in Spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176877/weird-nullpointerexception-in-spinner) but the suggested fixes have no effect.

The fragment is managed inside a FragmentPagerAdapter taken from [Cheesebaron](http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2013/07/fragments-and-viewpager-with-mvx.html).

Is this a Xamarin, MvvmCross, Android or pebcak issue?

Fragment:

```
public class XFragment : MvxFragment
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        OnCreateViewCalled += async (sender, args) =>
        {
            await ((IXViewModel)ViewModel).InitializeViewModelAsync();
        };
        var ignore = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        return this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.CreateCustomerProduct, null);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<MvxSpinner
                style="@style/formSpinner"
                android:id="@+id/MyComponent.spinnerX"
                android:prompt="@string/XPrompt"
                local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Xes; SelectedItem MyModel.X.Bouquet" />
```

Stack trace:

```
11-25 11:11:23.425 D/AndroidRuntime(20978): Shutting down VM
11-25 11:11:23.425 W/dalvikvm(20978): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41851b90)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978): Process: FSIA.Android, PID: 20978
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:6124)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:6400)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.widget.Spinner.setUpChild(Spinner.java:632)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.widget.Spinner.makeView(Spinner.java:595)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.widget.Spinner.getBaseline(Spinner.java:431)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1262)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1226)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:326)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1447)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2289)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16458)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1914)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1111)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1293)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-25 11:11:23.455 E/AndroidRuntime(20978):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533006/android-app-crashes-with-nullpointerexception-in-choreographer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176877/weird-nullpointerexception-in-spinner this looks like it's a kitkat change to do with `Ellipsize` in the standard template

Comment: Thanks. How would I go about compensating for the kitkat change as MvvmCross and Xamarin are in the middle?

Comment: @Stuart is there any workaround for this? I tried to remove all the `ellipsize` used in my Layouts w/o any success.

Comment: @michaelw13 check the Cheesebaron answer in this issue: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/507#issuecomment-29458182 it may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/507 this issue is fixed in 3.1.1