# java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [UnityChoreographer]

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Me and my team and I are experiencing crashes on our Game and this error comes up. anyone know why?

```
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [UnityChoreographer]
Unity version     : 2018.1.3f1

Caused by
  at $Proxy7.doFrame (Unknown Source)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:892)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:696)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:628)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:880)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:815)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:104)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like something to be rendered in Unity was destroyed/improperly created during rendering. This may happen when setting up UI when not in the main thread.

You can check the [choreographer code here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/56a2301/core/java/android/view/Choreographer.java?autodive=0%2F%2F). Android uses choreographer for timing animations, input, and drawing of views.

[Other android choreographer issues] ([Android app crashes with NullPointerException in ChoreoGrapher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533006/android-app-crashes-with-nullpointerexception-in-choreographer))