# httpClient.execute(httpPost) causing crash (Android 4.1)

Tags: android, httpclient, httpresponse

maybe you can help me out.  I'm working on an Android app project that calls on the Rotten Tomatoes API, which returns JSON data.  But whenever I run my code the application crashes.  The specific bit of code that's giving me problems is httpClient.execute(httpPost);

The url string that's being passed to the method is fine and returns the correct data when I type it in my browser, so I know that isn't the problem.  I'm kinda at a loss.  I've never had an issue with an HttpClient, though in the past I've only worked with XML, never JSON.

I've been struggling with this for a while now.  If anyone has any insight, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
 public JSONObject getJSON(String url) {
    //Make HTTP Request
    try {

        //defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        //Log.d("RunTest", url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost); // THIS LINE CAUSES APPLICATION TO CRASH
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        Log.d("Exceptions", "UnsupportedEncodingException");
        uee.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
        Log.d("Exceptions", "ClientProtocolException");
        cpe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.d("Exceptions", "IOException");
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

10-27 02:52:44.484: I/Choreographer(627): Skipped 147 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-27 02:52:44.704: W/dalvikvm(627): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
10-27 02:52:44.724: E/AndroidRuntime(627): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-27 02:52:44.724: E/AndroidRuntime(627): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-27 02:52:44.724: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
10-27 02:52:44.724: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
10-27 02:52:44.724: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
10-27 02:52:44.724: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
10-27 02:52:44.724: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-27 02:52:44.724: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-27 02:52:44.724: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-27 02:52:44.724: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-27 02:52:44.724: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-27 02:52:44.724: E/AndroidRuntime(627): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/box_office.json
10-27 02:52:44.724: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:591)
10-27 02:52:44.724: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293)
10-27 02:52:44.724: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
10-27 02:52:44.724: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
10-27 02:52:44.724: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
10-27 02:52:44.724: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at com.example.rottentomatoesclient.JSONParser.getJSON(JSONParser.java:39)
10-27 02:52:44.724: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at com.example.rottentomatoesclient.MoviesActivity$getMovieList.doInBackground(MoviesActivity.java:90)
10-27 02:52:44.724: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at com.example.rottentomatoesclient.MoviesActivity$getMovieList.doInBackground(MoviesActivity.java:1)
10-27 02:52:44.724: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-27 02:52:44.724: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-27 02:52:44.724: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  ... 5 more
10-27 02:52:44.774: W/ActivityManager(148):   Force finishing activity com.example.rottentomatoesclient/.MoviesActivity
```

Comment: I never get any LogCat errors.  None of the exceptions are ever thrown.

Comment: Have you given the `Internet` permission?

Comment: If your application crashed then definitely some logcat error will be produced.

Comment: may be Changing this line  `HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);` to `HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);` work hope this help.

Comment: Make sure you are not running this task on main UI thread

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I'm not thinking clearly anymore.  I added the logcat.

Comment: And I'm not.  It's being executed in a different thread via AsyncTask

Comment: Try to look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/q/11266535/940096

Comment: Your target host is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, your URL is probably *not* correct. In the middle of your long stack-trace you can find this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null,
path=api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists/movies/box_office.json
```

This looks like an error returned from the server - you did not supply all paramterers.

Comment: Ok, I'm an idiot.  I neglected to add the "http://" to the url string.  Apparently that's essential.  It also explains why it worked fine when I pasted the url into my browser's address bar.  Anyway it seems to be working fine now.  Thanks for all the help.