# Choreographer skipped frames! How many is too many?

Tags: android, performance

From time to time I can see a log entry similar to this one in logcat:

> Choreographer Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I know the meaning of this message (it's explained e.g. in here: [Meaning of Choreographer messages in Logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266535/meaning-of-choreographer-messages-in-logcat)) and this question is not about what the message means.

My question is: **how many skipped frames is too many?** Is there any kind of guidance (official or from experience) to say that about 50 is too much and less is ok? I don't really see any performance deterioration even on slower devices. Maybe I should not really worry about performance based just on this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how many skipped frames is too many?

1 is too many, according to some.

> Is there any kind of guidance (official or from experience) to say that about 50 is too much and less is ok?

50 would be rather bad. At 16ms per frame, that is 800ms that your UI is frozen. Users have a good chance of noticing this (e.g., they try tapping on a button and there is no visual response).

The more animated your UI is, the more likely it is that users will notice dropped frames. Dropping a frame on a fairly static UI may not be noticed; dropping a frame while the user is scrolling a `ListView` is more likely to be noticed. How sensitive users are to dropped frames varies by the user.

> Maybe I should not really worry about performance based just on this message?

IMHO, you should.

Comment: My UI skips around 2, 3 frames while starting the activity. I can't have much to optimize. But still it hurts me if I see missed frames. :(