# android app runtime error on phone

Tags: android, android-sqlite

This app runs fine on emulator but stops unexpectedly when installed on phone.
My app is having -

1. 7 Activities each having its own layout , AlertDialogs , menus and java class
2. A SQLiteHelper class having one database with two tables.
3. SQLiteHelper class has around 10 methods.

The app when run on emulator, sometimes logcat shows-
"Skipped 55 frames, the app may be doing too much work on mainthread"

- Is that too much for a phone to handle?
- Is there some basic mistake which I am doing?
- Are there some rules to be followed that I am not following?

Comment: Post some error generated in logcat. thnx

Comment: It runs fine on emulator.
The error occurs while running on phone

Comment: Here, "Skipped 55 frames...." is just Choreographer message but it's not related to app crashing.So, here something wrong at some other place.[Go to this questions about choreographer messages in logcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266535/meaning-of-choreographer-messages-in-logcat)

Comment: How can I know what is the problem??..coz there is no problem on emulator

Comment: Post your logcat when your app crashed into phone.