# Anyone can explain me my logcat?

Tags: java, android

this is my logcat when i run my app to detect the wifi and to see if it is connected, but i just dont know if its working.

`07-11 03:17:24.890: I/Choreographer(829): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 03:17:25.460: D/gralloc_goldfish(829): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-11 03:17:46.790: I/Choreographer(829): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 03:17:46.980: I/Choreographer(829): Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 03:17:54.920: D/WiFiChangeBroadcastReceiver(829): WiFi Status Changed
07-11 03:17:55.040: D/WiFiChangeBroadcastReceiver(829): WiFi Status Changed
07-11 03:18:38.240: I/Choreographer(829): Skipped 78 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 03:18:40.230: I/Choreographer(829): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 03:18:40.930: I/Choreographer(829): Skipped 131 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 03:22:24.850: I/Choreographer(829): Skipped 124 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 03:22:25.570: I/Choreographer(829): Skipped 338 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 03:22:25.680: I/Choreographer(829): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 03:22:40.180: I/Choreographer(829): Skipped 200 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 03:22:40.430: I/Choreographer(829): Skipped 86 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 03:22:43.610: I/Choreographer(829): Skipped 77 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 03:22:44.110: I/Choreographer(829): Skipped 104 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 03:22:44.210: I/Choreographer(829): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 03:25:50.470: I/Choreographer(829): Skipped 189 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 03:25:50.520: I/Choreographer(829): Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 03:25:51.430: I/Choreographer(829): Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 03:27:17.430: I/Choreographer(829): Skipped 103 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 03:27:18.090: I/Choreographer(829): Skipped 278 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 03:27:18.350: I/Choreographer(829): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 03:27:20.460: I/Choreographer(829): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 03:27:20.560: I/Choreographer(829): Skipped 82 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-11 03:27:22.160: I/Choreographer(829): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

Does this app detect my ip address?

Comment: read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266535/meaning-of-choreographer-messages-in-logcat

Comment: The code in your main thread is too work heavy. See http://vaibhavtolia.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/79/.

Comment: are you running this on a emulator?

Comment: I guess it is working,  `07-11 03:17:54.920: D/WiFiChangeBroadcastReceiver(829): WiFi Status Changed
07-11 03:17:55.040: D/WiFiChangeBroadcastReceiver(829): WiFi Status Changed`

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that we can know from your logcat is that you are using a **Emulator**;

> Emulator without GPU emulation detected.

The skipped frames is very common warning while running app in emulator and I would not consider it much when I am using a **Emulator**. But if it is showing in a device then you will certainly need to fix it. The warning **The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.** is shown even when we are displaying a simple UI like **progressdialog** in emulator.