# Room Coroutine is executed in main thread

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, android-mvvm

I am playing around with Kotlin Flow, Coroutines and Room. I am trying to insert data into my Room Database from my Repository.

When inserting a single item there is no problem but if I try to insert a list of items, the execution aborts and there is following message logged to the console:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I don't understand why the insert operation is executed on the main thread because according to the docs, a suspended DAO operation should always be executed in a Coroutine initiated internally by Room (which ultimately should run on a background thread). I also tried to run the insert call in another Scope explicitly (withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { ... }) but there is no difference.

Here is what my code looks like:

ViewModel:

```
fun setStateEvent(stateEvent: StateEvent) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        when (stateEvent) {
            is StateEvent.GetItems -> {
                repository.getItems().onEach { dateState ->
                    _dataState.value = dateState
                }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
suspend fun getItems(): Flow<DataState<List<Item>>> = flow {
    emit(DataState.Loading)
    try {
        val items = itemService.getAllItems()
        emit(DataState.Success(items))
        itemDao.insertItems(items) // The execution stops here
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        emit(DataState.Error(e))
    }
}
```

DAO:

```
@Insert
suspend fun insertItems(items: List<Item>)
```

I also tried to debug and find the source of the problem but I had no luck. Would be glad if anyone could tell me what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see, there is no problem here. [Choreographer messages can be misleading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11329209), it might have nothing to do with the main thread. I often see this when debugging, probably due to the debugger overhead. Inflation of heavy layouts can also cause it.

Also you don't need the `launchIn(viewModelScope)` because the flow is already collected in that scope. Just use `collect()`. And unlike what the other answers may suggest, you are right in saying the Room automatically switches the thread when using `suspend` DAO methods.

Comment: But the message does only appear when the `insertItems` function is called. Also I am sure that the execution is somehow interrupted because the items are not getting persisted and also, if I switch the `emit` and the `insertItems` function calls and set a breakpoint on the `emit` statement, the breakpoint is never reached, so the execution must have been interrupted while trying to persist the data.

BTW, thank you for the tip with `.collect()`!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys... There is no problem with the code from my original post.
I didn't evaluate the error I threw when catching the exception. So the problem was something completely different (NOT NULL constraint failed).

I didn't think about this because of the message with the main thread.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You can just add the Dispatchers.IO in the launch of the CoroutineScope that executes the viewmodelScope

```
fun setStateEvent(stateEvent: StateEvent) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        when (stateEvent) {
            is StateEvent.GetItems -> {
                repository.getItems().collect {
                for(item in it) { _dataState.value = item }
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure that you have the dependency of room-ktx in your gradle, this will allow you to use suspend functions inside your interface with room

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.5"
```

See: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#declaring_dependencies

Either way you won't be able to benefit from suspend in your room interface.

Comment: `repository.getItems()` is never call when using your suggested code. This can be fixed if `.collect()` is called after `.onEach()`. Nonetheless, then the following error occurs:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke setValue on a background thread`.

The dependency is already added.
Why would I not be able to benefit from suspend?

Comment: Inside collect do the dataState.value, I have changed the code, take a look at it

Comment: Same error. _dataState is of type `MutableLiveData` and the setValue method has to be called on the main thread. EDIT: Saw your edit right now, I will look at your code, thanks! EDIT2: This won't make a difference because it would still get called on an IO thread and setValue has to be called from the main thread.