# how to run some kind of repeating task every 30 minutes?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, scheduled-tasks

I need to setup some kind of repeating task to run every 30 minutes to do some checking and updating.

Like widgets (that are part of an app) are being updated every 30 minutes (if setup this way). I have a separate app which is only a widget and another app without a widget. Is it possible to update the widget for example every 30 minutes without the app running (like a widget that is part of an app) ?

Many thanks!

Comment: check this thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931032/android-process-scheduling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and setting up a repeating alarm. Here is some [example code](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Core-Class/Exampleofschedulingoneshotandrepeatingalarms.htm) I found. Here is [another](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/schedule-repeating-alarm.html).